# <base> tag is ignored for links inside SVG in Chrome

Tags: html, svg, iframe

I'm using the `<base>` tag to make links inside iframe open in the parent window.

So I add this to iframe's HTML:

```
<base target="_parent" />
```

In Chrome 121.0.6167.185 this works as expected on regular links, but **not links that are inside the SVG** - for some reason they ignore base tag and links open inside the iframe, not the parent window.

Both parent window and iframe are in the same domain.

E.g. the iframe content looks like this:

```
<base target="_parent" />

<a href="/some-page">Normal Link</a>

<svg height="60" width="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <a href="/some-other-page">
    <text x="0" y="15" fill="red">SVG Link</text>
  </a>
</svg>
```

First links opens in parent window, but second one opens inside the iframe. In Firefox both links respect <base> tag and open in parent window.

Any ideas why this happens and is there a workaround?

Comment: _"is there a workaround?"_ - since everything is from the same origin, nothing would stop you from using JavaScript to go through the elements in the iframe after it has loaded, and _set_ the `target` attribute for those links explicitly ...

Comment: You can report Chrome bugs to [Chrome's bugtracker](https://issues.chromium.org/issues)

Comment: @RobertLongson So this is a bug? Not me doing something wrong?

Comment: @RobertLongson I don't know, that's why im here. Thanks I guess